# How to integrate facebook notification in php?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have a toy winning website for kids. I have created a facebook app. I want to send notification to all the member of app when any kid wins a toy. how to handle this please support ASAP. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Notifications API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications/)  to send the notification to the app users.

**Remember**- your app must be a canvas app (app inside facebook)